# Firebase Function onCreate add to new collection works, but update does not

Tags: node.js, function, google-cloud-firestore

I have this onCreate Trigger, I am using it to aggregate and add record or update record.  First it takes minutes to add the record and then the update never runs just keeps adding, not sure why my query is not bringing back a record to update.

Any suggestion would be great.

```
exports.updateTotals = functions.runWith({tinmeoutSeconds: 540})
    .firestore.document("user/{userID}/CompletedTasks/{messageId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const mycompleted = snap.data();
      const myuserid = context.params.userID;
      console.log("USER: "+myuserid);
      const mygroup = mycompleted.groupRef;
      const myuser = mycompleted.userRef;
      const newPoints = mycompleted.pointsEarned;
      console.log("POINTS: "+newPoints);
      const data = {
        groupRef: mygroup,
        userRef: myuser,
        pointsTotal: newPoints,
      };
      const mytotalsref = db.collection("TaskPointsTotals")
          .where("groupRef", "==", mygroup)
          .where("userRef", "==", myuser);
      const o = {};
      await mytotalsref.get().then(async function(thisDoc) {
        console.log("NEW POINTS: "+thisDoc.pointsTotal);
        const newTotalPoints = thisDoc.pointsTotal + newPoints;
        console.log("NEW TOTAL: "+newTotalPoints);
        if (thisDoc.exists) {
          console.log("MYDOC: "+thisDoc.id);
          o.pointsTotal = newTotalPoints;
          await mytotalsref.update(o);
        } else {
          console.log("ADDING DOCUMENT");
          await db.collection("TaskPointsTotals").doc().set(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can you also provide the structure of your database ?

Comment: Not sure how to represent that, however the fields in the where are DocumentReferences and in the trigger collection which works fine, there are 4 DocumentReferences and a pointsEarned.

Comment: Hi I have updated the code can you take a look again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing this behavior because while querying for updates you are getting more than 1 document and you are using `thisDoc.exists` on more than one document. If you have used typescript this could have been catched while writing the code.

So for the update query, if you are confident that only unique documents exist with those filters then here’s the updated code that I have recreated using in my environment.

**functions/index.ts** :

```
exports.updateTotals = functions.runWith({timeoutSeconds: 540})
    .firestore.document("user/{userId}/CompletedTasks/{messageId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const mycompleted = snap.data();
      const myuserid = context.params.userID;
      console.log("USER: "+myuserid);
      const mygroup = mycompleted.groupRef;
      const myuser = mycompleted.userRef;
      const newPoints = mycompleted.pointsEarned;
      console.log("POINTS: "+newPoints);
      const data = {
        groupRef: mygroup,
        userRef: myuser,
        pointsTotal: newPoints,
      };
      const mytotalsref = admin.firestore()
          .collection("TaskPointsTotals")
          .where("groupRef", "==", mygroup)
          .where("userRef", "==", myuser);
      await mytotalsref.get().then(async function(thisDoc) {
        if (!thisDoc.empty) { // check if the snapshot is empty or not
          const doc = thisDoc.docs[0];
          if(doc.exists){
            const newTotalPoints = doc.data()?.pointsTotal + newPoints;
            const id = doc.id;
            await db.collection("TaskPointsTotals").doc(id).update({pointsTotal: newTotalPoints});
          }
        } else {
          await db.collection("TaskPointsTotals").doc().set(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

For more information about QuerySnapshot methods check [this docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html)

Comment: thanks for the help, however it throws a TypeError
```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exists')
```
It does not like the exists

Comment: I think its not bringing back the query because I am using a documentreference stored in the collection to see if its in the other collection.  Actually 2 of them.  Not sure if thats the issue or not.  In the console they of course match, so not sure why it would not work in the function.